# ant compiles no classes shown

Tags: xml, ant

I know this has been asked before, I've looked at those others and can't spot the problem. So Yea ant says build successful and the file hierarchy from the java package is recreated. I can confirm that the .java files ARE in the src folder. Here is my build.xml:

```
<project name="FlashcardShark" default="compile" basedir=".">

<property file="build.properties"/>
<property file="${user.home}/build.properties"/>

<property name="app.name"      value="FlashcardShark"/>
<property name="app.path"      value="/${app.name}"/>
<property name="app.version"   value="0.1"/>
<property name="build.home"    value="${basedir}/build"/>
<property name="catalina.home" value="/usr/share/tomcat7"/>
<property name="dist.home"     value="${basedir}/dist"/>
<property name="docs.home"     value="${basedir}/docs"/>
<property name="manager.url"   value="http://localhost:8080/manager/text"/>
<property name="src.home"      value="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="web.home"      value="${basedir}/web"/>

 <path id="compile.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${basedir}/lib/*"/>

    <fileset dir="${catalina.home}/bin">      
    <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <pathelement location="${catalina.home}/lib"/>
    <fileset dir="${catalina.home}/lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

    <pathelement path = "${env.J2EE_HOME}/${j2ee.jar}"/>
    <fileset dir = "lib">
      <include name = "**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

</path>


 <taskdef resource="org/apache/catalina/ant/catalina.tasks"
           classpathref="compile.classpath"/>


<property name="compile.debug"       value="true"/>
<property name="compile.deprecation" value="false"/>
<property name="compile.optimize"    value="true"/>


<target name="all" depends="clean,compile"
   description="Clean build and dist directories, then compile"/>


<target name="clean"
   description="Delete old build and dist directories">
    <delete dir="${build.home}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist.home}"/>
</target>


<target name="compile" depends="prepare"
   description="Compile Java sources">

    <!-- Compile Java classes as necessary -->
    <mkdir    dir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <echoxml>
    <javac srcdir="${src.home}"
          destdir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes"
            debug="${compile.debug}"
           includes="${basedir}/lib/**/*"
      deprecation="${compile.deprecation}"
         optimize="${compile.optimize}"
    failonerror="true">
    </javac></echoxml>

    <!-- Copy application resources -->
    <copy  todir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes">
      <fileset dir="${src.home}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
    </copy>

  </target>


<target name="dist" depends="compile,javadoc"
   description="Create binary distribution">

    <!-- Copy documentation subdirectories -->
    <mkdir   dir="${dist.home}/docs"/>
    <copy    todir="${dist.home}/docs">
      <fileset dir="${docs.home}"/>
    </copy>

    <!-- Create application JAR file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist.home}/${app.name}-${app.version}.war"
         basedir="${build.home}"/>

    <!-- Copy additional files to ${dist.home} as necessary -->

  </target>



<target name="prepare">
    <mkdir  dir="${build.home}"/>
    <mkdir  dir="${build.home}/WEB-INF"/>
    <mkdir  dir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/classes"/>

    <copy todir="${build.home}">
      <fileset dir="${web.home}"/>
    </copy>

    <mkdir  dir="${build.home}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

And the output from ant -verbose:

```
parsing buildfile /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build.xml with URI = file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build.properties
 [property] Loading /root/build.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: /root/build.properties
Override ignored for property "app.path"
Override ignored for property "catalina.home"
adding /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/lib/* which contains wildcards and may not do what you intend it to do depending on your OS or version of Java
Trying to override old definition of datatype resources
Build sequence for target(s) `compile' is [prepare, compile]
Complete build sequence is [prepare, compile, reload, install, remove, list, javadoc, clean, dist, all, ]

prepare:
    [mkdir] Skipping /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build because it already exists.
    [mkdir] Skipping /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF because it already exists.
    [mkdir] Skipping /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF/classes because it already exists.
     [copy] No sources found.
     [copy]  omitted as /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build is up to date.
    [mkdir] Skipping /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF/lib because it already exists.

compile:
    [mkdir] Skipping /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF/classes because it already exists.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<javac debug="true" deprecation="false" destdir="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF/classes" failonerror="true" includes="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/lib/**/*" optimize="true" srcdir="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/src" />
     [copy] No sources found.
     [copy]  omitted as /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF/classes is up to date.
     [copy] flashcardshark omitted as /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF/classes/flashcardshark is up to date.
     [copy] flashcardshark/bean omitted as /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF/classes/flashcardshark/bean is up to date.
     [copy] flashcardshark/servlet omitted as /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF/classes/flashcardshark/servlet is up to date.
     [copy] flashcardshark/utils omitted as /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/FlashcardShark/build/WEB-INF/classes/flashcardshark/utils is up to date.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

It says it cant find build.properties but I swear its right there next to build.xml. Any ideas thanks.

Comment: File permissions? Check that tomcat is able to read it.

Comment: Surely not, I am root.

Comment: tomcat usually runs by another user, not root, so that user could have problems to read files regardless of your permissions. In fact, the error is ` [property] Unable to find property file: /root/build.properties`.

Comment: ah I just restarted with a barebones build.xml. I am able to create a jar. I assume that means its working. I'm pretty sure I followed a tutorial that created a tomcat group but maybe I messed something up. How could I check ? thank you

Comment: I have this in tomcat-users:

Comment: <user username="maxbisesi" password="Epictetus12!" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui" />

Comment: Seems the problem has changed, build is working now but...? the build creates the classes right inside tomcat/webapps which is unusual in my opinion. I would suggest to follow a tutorial that builds a .war file on your user space, then deploy that war file on tomcat, that's the regular scenario.

Comment: Sorry but a .war and a .jar are the same here right ?

Comment: I have successfully create a .jar now I can deploy that my app folders web-inf folder in order to deploy ?

Comment: Nope, a war and a jar are not the same. A war is needed to deploy on tomcat.